# Why is the diff command in Mac OSX terminal unable to pick up file size differences Finder detects?

Tags: macos, diff

I recently used 7zip to create a .7z file from a folder I had. Afterwards, I unzipped the .7z file and then used finder to compare the differences between the two folders. It appeared that the two folders differed in size by about 200,000 bytes. Then, I used the diff command in Terminal to compare:

```
diff -rq folder1 folder2
```

To my surprise, nothing showed up. Is there anything to explain the difference? Is there a way to use diff to find why these show up with different sizes when I click on Get Info through Finder? Thanks.

Comment: Are the two directories on different filesystems, e.g. one on an HFS+ internal disk and one on a FAT32 USB-attached drive? The files can be the same as each other as reported by `diff`, but take up a different amount of space on disk depending on filesystems, block sizes, and layouts.

Comment: It is on the same hard drive. Is it possible when it created the zip to begin with, it went into my computer's cache first, then back, and hence the block size difference?